# Link Click - Javascript AJAX- file downloads, file extensions lost, real name lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a feature to download the file (PDF/DOCS/CSV/xlsx/JPEG/PNG/GIF) as given in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/szgh2fjj/)

I am using this way of downloading file because browser like firefox does not allow the image file to get downloaded, rather it opens up them in different tab.

Now here if you try hitting the "Click to download" link, the file does get downloaded but its real name and extension is lost.

I need some help in understanding how can this be achieved. Below is the code:

```
<a href="#" data-link="https://i.imgur.com/xSjQNTx.jpg">Click to download</a>
```

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"), i = 0, lnk;
while(lnk = links[i++]) {
  if (lnk.dataset.link.length) lnk.onclick = toBlob;
}

function toBlob(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var lnk = this, xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", lnk.dataset.link);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.overrideMimeType("octet/stream");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200)
      window.location = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
  return false
}
```

**NOTE:** I have referred to other SO posts but they didn't really helped

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just use the `download` attribute on an `<a>` element? Admittedly it's unsupported in IE11, but that's a tiny fraction of users.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it doesnt work with Firefox(Image opens in new tab) and IE